# How do I use the zip code gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*(Very new to Stack, please be gentle.)*

I'm wondering how to incorporate a zip code function into my app. The app is a forum of a sort-of Reddit-like quality. As it stands, Users can post, comment, CRUD, upload pictures, all that sort of thing.

The goal is to somehow include a person's zip code on their posts. Trouble is, I've no idea how to do that. I downloaded the [zip-codes gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/zip-codes), but I've no idea how to implement it.

Is there any idea how I can get help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought the zip code gem just had city/state info for a given zip code?

Comment: If you want to know how to use that particular gem the instructions are included on github https://github.com/monterail/zip-codes

Comment: The zip code gem just provides "extra" data to a zip code, so lets say your zip code is 10014, you can run identify and get the city and state,  New York, NY in this case.  If you want people to add their zip code when they post perhaps asking for it is better?

Answer (score 0):

The zipcodes gem just has city/state data for a given zipcode. If you want to get a user's location from their IP you'll want to look into something like [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) which adds a `location` method to the request hash:

```
def create
  @post = post.new(post_params)
  @post.zipcode = request.location.postal_code

  if @post.save
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

For a lighter weight solution, check out [freegeoip.net](https://freegeoip.net). You can send a request to a url like `https://freegeoip.net/json/70.123.123.13` and grab the zipcode from the response.